# Ajax php post not authenticating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a sample script that will authenticate my users to access the page. My issue is when I post the values the js file does reflect that the data has been serialized but when it is posted to the php file to check if the database record exists the users still gets access to the page whether the login in details are correct or wrong. For some reason it seems not to take my `$_POST['pass'] and my $_POST['user_email'] values. But if I manually type in the user email and password in the php file to replace the variables it will works.

HTML form

```
<form class="login" id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post">
    <p class="title">LOGIN</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="user_email" name="user_email" autofocus/>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" name="pass" />
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
     <button>
      <i class="spinner" style="outline:none;"></i>
      <span class="state">Log in</span>
    </button>
  </form>
```

My js file to post the values. I added the console.log just to test see what values are been taken in by the script

```
$('document').ready(function()
{ 
    var working = false;
    $('.login').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(working)return
        working = true;
        var $this = $(this),
        $state = $this.find('button > .state');
        $this.addClass('loading');
        $state.html('Authenticating');

        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'login_process.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(response) {                     
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response=="ok"){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $this.addClass('ok');
                            $state.html('Welcome');

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $state.html('Log in');
                                $this.removeClass('ok loading');
                                working = false;
                            }, 4000);

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                window.location.href = "/Home.aspx";
                            }, 4000);  
                        }, 3000);           
                        //$("#btn-login").html('<img src="btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Signing In ...');
                        //setTimeout(' window.location.href = "home.php"; ',4000);
                    } else {
                        console.log('ERROR IN LOGINING IN');    
                    }
              }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

PHP file 'login_process'

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    if(isset($_POST['pass']))
    {
        $user_email = urldecode(trim($_POST['user_email']));
        $user_password =trim($_POST['pass']);
        //$password = md5($user_password);
        $password = $user_password;
        try {   

            $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_email=:email");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$user_email));
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();

            if($row['user_password']==$password){
                echo "ok"; // log in
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
            }
            else{
                echo "email or password does not exist."; // wrong details 
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is being returned from ajax call?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: My main question is why is it not taking my $_POST values in my php. file

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the dataType make with dataType : 'json' just after data, You can return the result in json by json_encode() ti debug result